# Gridview DataBind table not showing VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I am trying to display data to a Gridview in ASP.Net (using VB) but the table won't appear on my page.
I have created a small test page to see what is the problem, but I can't seem to find any issues. Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" Title="Test Website" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
        <div>
            Before Table
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="100%"  ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            After Table
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And the backend code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Test
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       If Not IsPostBack() Then
           Dim dt As New DataTable()
           dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)),
                                                      New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)),
                                                      New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})
           dt.Rows.Add(1, " Dionysos Greta ", "USA")
           dt.Rows.Add(2, "Traci Khan", "India")
           dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Malle", "France")
           dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Smith", "Whales")
           GridView1.DataSource = dt
           GridView1.DataBind()
       End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Edit:
Here is an image of what is shown in the page:

[Image of what can be seen when page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3R83.png)

Edit 2: After setting AutoEventWireup to "false", the page would not load the GridView. No errors occur when debugging.

Thank you.

Comment: The code seems ok, did you debug it?

Comment: I did debug it but no errors seemed to appear. The code ran normally, but the gridview just didn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design source didn't like the `<div>` tag inside the grid. You seem to have a grid inside a grid. Is that what you intended? I got rid of the extra grid and it works fine. If you need an a grid in a grid then you need to tell the design what column and row in the outer grid the inner gird belongs. First you need to add some columns and rows to the outer grid.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I off loaded the grid code to a separate Sub so the Page_Load isn't so cluttered.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub FillGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)),
                                               New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)),
                                               New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})
    dt.Rows.Add(1, " Dionysos Greta ", "USA")
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Traci Khan", "India")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Malle", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Smith", "Whales")
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! This seems to be working!

Comment: @pleasehelpanoob If my answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it be clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will help future readers and earn you a few points as well as earn me a few. This is the best way to thank people on Stack Overflow.